# How to optimize while loop with SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

```
$id = $user['id']; // the ID of the logged in user, we are retrieving his friends
$friends = $db->query("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE accepted='1' AND (user1='".$id."' OR user2='".$id."') ORDER BY id DESC");

while($friend = $friends->fetch_array()) {
    $fr = $db->query("SELECT id,profile_picture,age,full_name,last_active FROM users WHERE (id='".$friend['user1']."' OR id='".$friend['user2']."') AND id != '".$id."'")->fetch_array(); 
    echo $fr['age'];     
}
```

I am basically looping through all my friends, and getting information about each one.

How would I ago about optimizing this, I am aware that that it is inefficient to run this query so many times, considering there are thousands of "friends", but I'm not exactly sure how to go about optimizing it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: and the problem being what; speed?

Comment: yes, speed is a big issue because there are many users.

Comment: run your select first, then do your loop and make sure your table is properly indexed. You could also look into pagination and LIMIT to name a few. I also don't know why you're using `fetch_array()` twice.

Comment: seeing your edit; you could use some type of JOIN also, rather than 2 seperate queries. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Use pagination for that if you have a big query.

Comment: Can you join those tables together in your SQL so you query once and loop to get data from structure?

Comment: I'm already using pagination, but i'm also interested in a more elegant way to do this, only with a single select query (possibly a join) I'll have a look at the article @Fred-ii- referenced me to.

Comment: Yes, use a join. For pagination, use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to avoid having to re-run an almost identical query to get the total rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article in the comments is great. You're definitely going to want to figure out how to write the join yourself. Here's my attempt at writing it for you. While you're rewriting the query, you might want to not * columns from friend_requests (or any at all since you're going to use the join). Any column you pull will have to be loaded into memory so any you can avoid pulling will help out. Especially if you're PHP server and your DB server are not on the same machine (less data over the network).

Anyway, here's my shot in the dark:

```
$id = $user['id'];

$friends = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        freq.* 
        ,users.id AS users_id
        ,users.profile_picture
        ,users.age
        ,users.full_name
        ,users.last_active
    FROM friend_requests freq
    INNER JOIN users u ON users.id IN (freq.user1,freq.user2) AND freq.id != u.id
    WHERE
        freq.accepted='1'
        AND ? IN (freq.user1,freq.user2
    ORDER BY freq.id DESC");
if($friends) {

    $friends->bindParam("s",$id);

    if($friends->execute()) {
        // get_result() only works if you have the MySQL native driver. 
        // You'll find out real quick if you don't
        $myFriends = $friends->get_result();

        while($row = $myFriends->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['age'];     
        }
    }
}
else {
    printf("SQL Error: %s.<br>\n", $friends->error);
}
// cleanup
$friends->close();
```

quick reference: [get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

Comment: A good shot. Note that $id doesn't need to be punctuated - but it should be rewritten to take advantage of prepared statement syntax, and numeric values don't need to and shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: @Strawberry  been a while since i used mysqli so, I'd appreciate it if you checked out the edit